# convert string (4/14/2016 8:00:00 PM) to timestamp in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp

Could you please help to convert String to DateTime in Bigquery?
The length of String are different below, cause there's no 0 in a single number of date month, hour.

4/14/2016 8:00:00 PM

5/7/2016 5:00:00 P

I try to use PARSE_TIMESTAMP function but error "Failed to parse input string "4/14/2016 8:00:00 PM""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below

```
select parse_timestamp('%m/%d/%Y %r', col) ts
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works!! I am very new in SQL and bigquery and really appreciate your help